# vector argument in c++ class

Tags: c++, class, vector

I would like to create a C++ Class which takes a "vector" int t[9] as argument. I don't understand why my code isn't working :

Here is the content of the header :

```
class Matrice3x3{
public:
    int n;
    int t[9];
    Matrice3x3 inverse();
    float det();
    void print();
    Matrice3x3(int u = 3);
    Matrice3x3(int p[9], int m = 9);
private:
};
```

And here the content of the class description :

```
Matrice3x3::Matrice3x3(int u) {
    n = u*u;
}

Matrice3x3::Matrice3x3(int p[9] , int m){
    n = m;
    t = p;
}
```

And i get this error :

```
In constructor 'Matrice3x3::Matrice3x3(int*, int)':
incompatible types in assignment of 'int*' to 'int [9]'
t = p;
  ^
```

I just don't see where i said one of the [] was a pointer...

thanks for answering!

Comment: 1) in your header, replace `int t[9];` by `int *t;`, and the adress assigned must be allocated before. 2) why do you uses 'n' if your type is Matrix3x3 ? n is egal to 9 in any case if it's a 3x3 matrix.

Comment: pour le 2) c'est parce que la question suivante de mon exercice passe à la généralisation aux matrices nxn :)

Comment: google for "arrays decay to pointers"

Comment: @Gullfaxi171: in the constructor `Matrice3x3(int p[9] , int m)`, you may replace `t = p` by `for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) t[i] = p[i];` and let `int t[9]` in this case in your class declaration. You will need a pointer `int *t` to allocate (sizeof(int) * n) when you will do your question 2).

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant please use English on SO.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot copy arrays like this. You should copy them element by element or use memcpy.
In general case it is better to use standard library for containers (std::vector in this case). You should have strong reason to prefer C-style array to standard container.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you really want fixed sized arrays, use C++11's std::array<> (Boost has a definition as well, for pre C++11). You can allocate it as std::array < int, 9 > and then pass it around as an object. You can also use the size() member function to get the number of elements (although its hardcoded in the type) and it has other member functions (such as begin() and end()) which make it look like a std container, so you can use std's algorithms on it as well. Basically, a wrapper around a fixed sized array. Of course you can pass by value of reference.